# Couchbase - Run on bucket file to get all keys of specific node

Tags: nosql, couchbase

I am currently working with couchbase server 1.8.1 an in a process of upgrading to 2.2 version.

We want to dump all the keys of couchbase 1.8.1 to a text file and then run on this file and copy all the data to the new couchbase 2.2.

The reason we chose to use this method instead of backup and restore is because our server do not respond well to backup and there is a risk of server failing.

Can you help me figure out how to create this dump file from couchbase bucket files?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what Dave posted, I recommend reading this blog post: http://blog.couchbase.com/Couchbase-rolling-upgrades

Also, there are some unique considerations when upgrading from 1.8.1 to 2.x, so make sure you read the documentation Dave linked to.

Answer (score 3):

Note you can upgrade an existing cluster online (without having to manually copy data to a new 2.2 cluster) - see http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-install/#upgrading

Answer (score 0):

We use this script: [CouchbaseDump](https://github.com/couchtim/couchbase-stuff/blob/08a8abd2c076ca608529b5bdfe9d8ad12c1e7ff2/dump-keys-sqlite3.sh)

It works and help us getting the keys from the sqlite files.